# Using log to take derivative of a function

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

Is it safe to say that if 
$\frac{d}{dx}ln(f)= g $ for some functions f and g, then 
$\frac{d}{dx}f = e^{g}$? Why or why not?

(novice high schooler here)

Comment: No. Suppose $f(x) = e^x$. Then $\ln(f(x)) = x$ and hence $(d/dx)\ln(f(x)) = 1$. That is, $g(x) = 1$. Now calculate $df/dx$ and compare it with $e^g$.

Comment: Why not try it out with some test functions?

Comment: This is so cool. Can jsut post my question about my hw here ! ^_^

Comment: Hmm ... we don't like doing HW so I'm sorry I gave it away too quickly. Here's a follow up for you: do there exist functions $f, g$ such that those two equations do hold?

Comment: Assume $\frac{d}{dx}ln[f]=g$. Then $\int{g}=ln(f)+c$. Then $e^{\int{g} } = e^{ln(f)+c}=f\times{e^{c}}$. Then $f = e^{\int{g}-c}$. Then $f'=ln(f+c)\times{f}\times{e^{c}} \neq{} e^{g}$. So, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "no" as pointed out in the comments.  You can however do the following:

$\frac{d}{dx} \ln(f(x)) = \frac{1}{f(x)}\cdot f^{\prime}(x)$ by the chain rule.
So, if $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(f(x))=g(x)$ then $f^{\prime}(x)=f(x)g(x)$.  This is usually called "logarithmic differentiation" and tends to show up in text books near applications of derivatives or implicit differentiation.